# approximate 3dB frequencies of an amplifier

Tags: operational-amplifier

[image]

- C3=40nF
- C2=0.5pF
- C1=2pF
- C4=infinity

Op amps are ideal.

C3 determines the low 3dB frequency and the other ones account for the high 3db frequency.

I would like to estimate the 3dB frequency of this amplifier using the time constants method.

for example, C2 sees "R4", but as I connect a voltage source between its terminals and short C1 and the original voltage source ,How can I find the current that flows through ? How might Op1 respond If connect a voltage source to its output?

And in the case of C3, Would it "see" just R7 because the voltage at the node connecting R8,R7 and R8 is zero ?

Comment: dB, capital B ;) fixing this...

Comment: uh, you say "obviously", and I must admit I need a bit of staring at this three-opamp active filter to understand exactly what happens. What kind of filter (band-, high-pass, multi-band?) is this?

Comment: I'm mostly confused because R8 and (R7--C3) form a (complex) voltage divider, but it's not per se an unloaded one (I don't think we can make that simplification), so that the whole feedback look around OP2 becomes more complicated.

Comment: And C4, if anything, also defines a lower cutoff frequency, not a higher one.

Comment: C4 tends to infinity, I fixed that. Thanks for your attention.

Comment: Are you sure? If C4 tends to infinity, then replace it with a straight connection. That makes R9 uneffictive as well, so removing that mentally. If that was right, why did they include R9 to begin with?

Comment: We won't do your homework for you. You need to show us that you have made a **substantial effort** to solve this yourself. Show us all of your work and explain your reasoning.